# Are weapons questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, tags

For example, this mine question:

- [How and why to build FTL weapon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/488/36)

I think, that weapons are essential parts of every world (or story), being build, but I'd like to have some confirmations (or disagree) from other community members.

If questions about weapons are on topic, then do we need [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag?

Comment: If properly scoped and asked yes... though I am not sure we need a weapons tag yet.

Comment: I agree, maybe use warfare for the time being?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think weapons are no more or less on-topic than plants, animals, or gravity.

That is to say, if your question relates to **how weapons fit into your world** or **what weapons your world may have** or something like that, then it's on topic.  If your question relates to how a given weapon may work, it's not likely to be on topic.

I don't think we need a specific tag for it, any more than we need one for any of those others.

Answer (score 4):

I voted to close the linked question since it was written as a fishing expedition, not a problem that needs a solution.

If the question was written asking about a particular in-world problem, then I would agree that it is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that an expert on medieval weapons could use that expertise to answer a question about this FTL weapon, and since tags are for ease experts work to answer questions, I do not think the tag could work.

Besides, they are on-topic if they are not real weapons with known effects, which should go to (possibly) Physics.SE.com (hard to draw the line, as always).

Comment: FTL weapon is just a pure example (which itself turned out to be rather off-topic). But `weapons` tag is, aside of this, needed in general, if we're going to ask about weapons. No matter, if medieval or future. Just weapons. Parts of worldbuilding, right? Or not?

Comment: Part of worldbuilding yes, but suitable for a tag, no. Most probably an expert in swords can answer a question about lightsabers, but not about the Death Star ray.